# AWS ALB - Same string in URL should go to same EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing, haproxy, amazon-elb

I want to achieve custom load balancing. My requirement is as follows.
I have application with URL pattern like

```
dns-name.com/conference1/abc......
dns-name.com/conference2/xyz......
dns-name.com/conference1/abc......
dns-name.com/conference3/pqr......
```

I want all users from different IP/browsers coming with URL conference1 should go to same instance under ALB until its up and running.

conference1 string is not fixed and we get that dynamically by application so path based routing not helping.

As users are different AWS ALB with Sticky Session also not helping.

Is there any solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "should go to same instance under ALB until its up and running"?

Comment: If first user with string in URL (conference1)   www.dns-name.com/conference1/abc........  goes to server1  then all other users with string conference1 in URL  should go to server1  (if server 1 is up and running   else server 2)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a solution that relies on built-in capabilities of Application Load Balancer (ALB) or any other type of ELB.

ALB uses static rules to route requests to target groups and expects all members of a given target group to be able to handle the request.

You either will need to design the service to eliminate the need for such an early routing decision, or you'll need another (custom) service layer behind the ALB.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built capability to do this.

One option is to slightly change the URL. Instead of:

```
dns-name.com/conference1/abc...
```

use:

```
conference1.dns-name.com/abc...
```

This would allow you to **direct traffic at the DNS level**, so all traffic to that URL would go to one IP address. Of course, you would need to define that DNS sub-domain before it was used by any traffic.

This, of course, pretty much **removes the need for the Load Balancer**, since you don't actually want to balance any traffic in the traditional manner.

However, the best advice is probably to reconsider your application architecture to **remove the need to direct such traffic to specific servers**. This requirement makes the system more prone to failure if an instance should fail. It is also more difficult to scale-out in case of traffic spikes (since all `conference1` traffic only goes to one instance), nor is it easy to scale-in to reduce costs.